# SQL Server and Oracle Extended/External Procedures Compatibility

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, dll

Is a extended/external stored procedure written in C and currently working under SQL Server viable to work under Oracle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C library is a C library, so your DLL ought to work as well in Oracle as SQL Server.  The difference is in the syntax for coding the wrappers.  The Oracle documentation covers this.  [Find out more.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/win.101/b10113/apps.htm#i1005844)